# Block Feature activation for a site template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, feature-activation

Is it possible to block feature activation for a specific site template in SharePoint using C#?

Comment: Interesting question. I would say this is not possible unless you somehow manage the "block" by removing users permissions to do so - any other way to achieve this that I can think of would need a global Feature Activated event handler that would get called every time any feature is called, and I don't think that exist. Any way, I will have a look and see if any workaround comes to mind.